# Node.js getting around 'listener must be a function' error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using Node.js and [steam-node](https://github.com/seishun/node-steam) to write a couple of bots for steam (stored on an Array), each bot has their own account and stuff. So, to begin, here's a part of my code:

```
function onLogon(index){
    console.log('[STEAM] Logged in on bot ' + index);
    bots[index].setPersonaState(Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
    /*do other stuff*/
}

for (var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){ /*Foreach of the bots, assign a loggedOn even listener */
    bots[i].on('loggedOn', onLogon(i));
}
```

And this code is giving me a 'listener must be a function'. Now, i know what this error means, i should set the event listener like this:

```
bots[i].on('loggedOn', onLogon);
```

but that doesnt work, because i need to pass a variable to the event.

I could do this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++){
    bots[i].on('loggedOn', function() {
        console.log('[STEAM] Logged in on bot ' + i);
        bots[i].setPersonaState(Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
        //...
    });
}
```

but it also doesnt work because i is passed by reference and it throws a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'setPersonaState' of undefined` that way.

```
bots[i].on('loggedOn', (function(index) {
        console.log('[STEAM] Logged in on bot ' + i);
        bots[index].setPersonaState(Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
        //...
    })(i));
```

And this ALSO doesn't work...

Is there ANY way to do what I want here? Or should I just dont use arrays?

Comment: There's an even simpler solution to this, just create a closure, and you can do that with `bots.forEach(function(bot) { ...` etc.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pymw4b3r/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
bots[i].on('loggedOn', onLogon(i));
```

you are *immediately* calling `onLogon`, and passing the result to `on`.  What you really want is to bind the first argument without calling it, which can be done as follows:

```
bots[i].on('loggedOn', onLogon.bind(null, i));
```

The `null` is because the first argument to `bind` is the context (or `this` value), which we don't care about.

Comment: Thanks man, worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

@Aaron's answer is probably the way to go, but as alternative, an enclosure might work.

```
function onLogon(bot, index){
    return function() {
        console.log('[STEAM] Logged in on bot ' + index);
        bot.setPersonaState(Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
        /*do other stuff*/
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){ /*Foreach of the bots, assign a loggedOn even listener */
    bots[i].on('loggedOn', onLogon(bots[i], i));
}
```

Or to build on @Aaron's answer, pass the bot as the function context.

```
function onLogon(index){
    console.log('[STEAM] Logged in on bot ' + index);
    this.setPersonaState(Steam.EPersonaState.Online);
    /*do other stuff*/
}

for (var i = 0; i < bots.length; i++){ /*Foreach of the bots, assign a loggedOn even listener */
    bots[i].on('loggedOn', onLogon.bind(bots[i], i));
}
```